# Problem while Designing a Database

Tags: sql, ms-access, data-transfer

I am in a mission to devise an application database in MS ACCESS.  In my database there are 5 tables:

- Master
- Cash
- Cheque
- Detail
- Month (displays month in a year)

Here I have made Master as parent record and 3 others Cash, Cheque and Detail are children to Master table.

Here are the fields in master table

```
   Lt no   Name  Regfee  AssessmentYear  April May June .......... March
```

The last 12 fields are months in a financial which takes amount as value.

These values should be populated from cheque/cash table through a query.

```
 
 cheque
   LTno **month** chqueno date bank **amount** are fields.
```

In this cheque table  amount for a particular month is to be populated on master table for the corresponding month. What query do I make.

Expecting your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I recommend using SQL Server Express (free, or other free databases) instead, because your MASTER table would usually be implemented as a View so you wouldn't need to use INSERT/UPDATE statements to populate the table.

Comment: bony M, what is your objective with this database?   What are you trying to do?

Comment: Rexem, I have no idea what your comment means.

Comment: @Tony: It's really poor design to store a summary value, for sake of overhead and maintenance.  A view is a "view" of table data, and only exists as it is queried.  I recommend the use of a view for  the month by month values (translated into SUM(amount) grouped by month & year) of the `MASTER` table.

Comment: The objective of the database appears to be the Accounts Payable (AP) and Accounts Receivable (AR) components of an accounting system, where `MASTER` is the General Ledger (GL).

Comment: @rexem: There is no need to upsize to SQL Server to get a "view" that is basically a pivot table -- ferchrissakes, the Access UI provides a wizard to walk you through just that process. You are right that the data is denormalized and needs to be restructured, but you are completely off-base suggesting this is something that can't be done in Access with a Jet/ACE data store.

Comment: Your structure is wrong. Fix that and you'll have an easier time reporting on your data.

Comment: @David: If suggesting a *free*, **more capable alternative to MS Access** is wrong, then I don't want to be right.  But good luck with convincing anyone otherwise ;)

Comment: @rexem - He already has Access. You suggest he get a refund from Microsoft? I don't see SQL Server or or some free .NET tool being a practical solution based on the question.

Comment: Rexem, ok, now I understand your suggestion about the views better.  It just wasn't making any sense to me.   I see David Fenton has already responded with other comments.

Answer (score 3):

As the database is not normalised, you will have to make a very complicated query to update the table. You have to either make twelve updates that look almost the same, or a huge query that does almost the same thing twelve times.

It would be better to move the month values out of the master table and into a separate table where the month is a field in the table instead of a field name. Then it would be easy to add the records to it:

```
insert into MasterMonths (LTno, month, value)
select LTno, month, sum(amount)
from cheque
group by LTno, month
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, except that I include credit card slips and cash purchases as well as checks.  It's basic bookkeeping.

For a variety of reasons, I chose to have a table called "almanac" with one row (record) for every date.  There are columns (fields) for such things as day of the week, month of the year, and so on.  I populate this table with a little code fragment written in VB.  Even with ten years worth of dates, that's only about 3,653 rows in the table.  I then use simple joins with this table to reduce transaction data to data that's summarized by month.  I can summarize in other ways, too.

The query is so easy that I just did it with the graphical query interface.  However, my summary would have twelve times as many rows as yours, with only one month in each row.

When I want data laid out in the format of your master table, I use one of two tools:  the crosstab query tool in MS Access, or the Pivot Table tool in MS Excel.  They are both very powerful, but the pivot tool is more flexible.  I had to install an add in called MS query in Excel in order to query database data from Excel.  That may be a function of the version I'm using.

This is very different from your framework, and it's your choice whether to use it.  It's worked well for me.